# Data table and dynamic button

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ado.net

I have a database(opos)which contains a table (unpaidchecks). I want to first all check if the data contains data and if it does I want to loop through it and compare the data from one of the columns (user) to libuser. Text , then if it’s the same I creat a dynamic button. The buttons are supposed to be created when the form loads

```
        unpaidcheck uk = new unpaidcheck();
    oposEntities gg = new oposEntities();                                             private void Interface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
       
        if (gg.unpaidchecks.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in gg.uk. 
            {
                if (uk.user.Contains(this.libuser.Text))
                {

                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.Location = new Point(3 + i, 14 + x);
                    btn.Width = 160;
                    btn.Height = 80;
                    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    btn.Text = "Tabel" + item["tabel_no_"] .ToString();
                    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                    this.panel3.Controls.Add(btn);
                    i += 10;
                    x += 10;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is the `mark` a `System.Data.DataTable`?

Comment: Yea it is a tabel in my database which I want to loop trough and use the data

Comment: You should compare to the loop variable `item` rather than mark. Such as `if(this.libuser.Text == item.user. )`.